# Innerhtml not retaining selected options for Selectbox and Radio in Mozilla and Chrome but works fine in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, standards-compliance

I have an application with several tabs, each of them having couple of fields. The last tab is Preview tab wherein I would like to show all the controls from all tabs in grayed color in uneditable mode. To do that, I am taking innerhtml of all tabs and showing the same in Preview tab.

While this logic works fine for Text fields, Select fields and Radio fields are not retaining their selected options in Mozilla and Chrome. It works as expected in IE 7, 8 and 9 too.

Any clue on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `clone()` method to make a copy of it instead of using the `innerHTML` property.

Example in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLB5s/

Comment: Even clone() is displaying the content of text fields but not the selected options of Select fields and Radio fields.